# Probability of being selected from two different groups

Tags: probability, statistics, problem-solving

I need help on doing some calculations regarding probability

Group A has 50 people, and group B has 300 people. All the members of both groups apply for the same selection process, and the selected people form a new group C

Out of group A’s 50 people, 20 people are chosen to group C. Out of group B’s 300 people, 60 people are chosen. That means 40% of group A was chosen and 20% of the people from group B were chosen.

Everyone were selected through the same selection process, so groups A and B were ”kind of” combined to a group AB, and from group AB a total amount of 80 (20+60) people were chosen to be a part of group C. We can clearly see, that if you were originally from group A, you were more likely to be selected for group C, but **how do you calculate how much more probable it was for someone from original group A to be chosen over someone from original group B?**

Other way to think about this: 50men and 300women apply for the same job(yes theyre looking for 80 employees in this case). 20 men were chosen and 60 women were chosen. How much more likely was it for a man to get the job, given that 40% of men were chosen and only 20% of women were chosen

Comment: If a group has $n$ people, and $k$ people from this group are selected, where $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~k \in \{0,1,2\cdots, n\}$ then the chances that any specific person in the group is selected is $\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}$.

Comment: @user2661923 ty! What you said is true, i’m trying to calculate a bit further.  We can see that if you were a part of the group A, you were more likely to be selected, since 40% of original group A were selected, and 20% of original group B were selected. If the selection process was separate for A & B, it would have been 20% more likely to be selected from group A yes? But original groups A & B were combined to new group AB and went through the same selection, so its not the case? Im lookin how to find out how much more probable the selection was for former group A member over former B member

Comment: It doesn't matter that A and B were *kind of combined* into group C.  The critical factor is that [1] $60$ people go into group C [2] Of those $60$ *slots*, $20$ of those *slots* are reserved for people from group A, and the remaining slots are reserved for people from group B.  An alternatively specification is that the $350$ people in A and B combined form a single group, and of that group, $60$ people are chosen.  This is **a different problem** from the problem that you first presented.  In this different problem, you would expect that about $10$ of the $60$ people chosen would be from A.

Comment: Re the **different** problem, the reason for my conclusion is that the ratio of people from A to people from B, in the combined group of $350$ people is $1 ~: ~6$, so you would (statistically) expect that same ratio when the $60$ people are chosen from the $350$ people.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks for the comments again! I had a typo there (60 total selected, even though it was 20+60=80). Also tried to make what im after more clear. Other way to Think about this is: 50men and 300women apply for the same job(yes theyre looking for 80 employees in this case). 20 men were chosen and 60 women were chosen. How much more likely was it for a man to get the job, given that 40% of men were chosen and only 20% of women were chosen

Comment: @user2661923 or am i just thinking about this too deep? I’ll continue the man/woman example from my previous comment: if 40% of male applicants were chosen, and 20% of female applicants were chosen, would i as a man have 20% bigger chance of being chosen? Does it not matter, that males and females were in the same recruitment process and not separate? Since for every man chosen, 3 women were also chosen, but for every man not chosen (total of 30) 8 women were not chosen(240 in total)?